# Calculating eigenvectors using dhsein in CLAPACK

Tags: c, numerical-methods, lapack, eigenvector

Here is my procedure:

```
int getEigenvector(FLOAT* matrix, FLOAT* eigenvalues, int selectedValueIndex, FLOAT* eigenvector, long size){
    char side = 'R'; // We want to calculate the right eigenvector.
    char source = 'Q'; // The eigenvalues come from HSEQR routine.
    char initVectors = 'N'; // No eigenvectors are provided.
    long* selectedValue = malloc((size) * sizeof(long));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        selectedValue[i] = 1;
    } 
    long workspaceSize = size * (size+2);
    FLOAT* workSpace = allocateVector(workspaceSize);
    long* fail = malloc(size * sizeof(long));
    long info = 0;
    long output = 0;
    long one = 1;
    HSEIN(&side, &source, &initVectors, selectedValue, &size, matrix, &size, eigenvalues, eigenvalues + size, 
     NULL, &one, eigenvector, &size, &size, &output, workSpace, NULL, fail, &info);
    printf("Info: %ld Output: %ld\n" , info, output);
    return info;
}
```

It is supposed to calculate the eigenvectors of given Heissenberg matrix (which I first calculate using HSEQR earlier).

No matter if I put 'Q' or 'N' as a source, given matrix 
`{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}` returns me this:

> Info: 0 Output: 2
>    0001.0000  -000.0000  0000.0000
>    0000.0000  -000.0000  0000.0000
>    0000.0000  0001.0000  0000.0000

(the numbers come from eigenvector array)

How is it even possible for that to only compute 2 vectors for a 3x3 matrix with 3 different eigenvalues?